# How to add pause functionality using events and listeners

Tags: java

```
public class CardGame implements KeyListener
    {
       static Player[] players;
       static int handSize;
       static Queue<Card>[] playingDeckArray;
       static int playersNum;
       static Object game;
       static boolean pressed = false;
       static boolean running = true;

       public static void main(String[] args){
            Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println( "\nHello, how many players would you like" );
            playersNum = Integer.parseInt(Checks.userInputCheck( "\\d" ));
            System.out.println( "\nHow many cards should each player begin with" );
            int handSize = Integer.parseInt(Checks.userInputCheck( "\\d" ));
            System.out.println( "\nWhich strategy would you like to use 1 or 2" );
            int strategy = Integer.parseInt(Checks.userInputCheck( "[12]$" ));

            Logger.createDeck( playersNum, handSize );

            makePlayers( playersNum, handSize, strategy );

            makePlayingDecks( playersNum );

            dealInitialHand( playersNum, players, handSize );

            makePlayerOutputs();

            MyKeyListenerThread elt = new MyKeyListenerThread();
            PauseGenerator pG = new PauseGenerator();

            pG.addMyKeyListener(elt);

            elt.start();
            pG.start();

            //makeDeckOutputs();

            for ( int i = 0; i < players.length; i++){
               logInitialHand(players[i]);
            }

            for ( int i = 0; i < players.length; i++){
               isWinner( players[i]);
            }

            for ( int i = 0; i < players.length; i++){
                new Thread( players[i] ).start();
            }

            while(running){
                String input = reader.next();
                System.out.println( input );
                if ( input == "p" ){
                    System.out.println( "pressed" );
                    CardGame.pressed = true;
                }else if( input == "r" ){
                    System.out.println( "pressed" );
                    CardGame.pressed = false;
                }
            }
       }

static class PauseGenerator extends Thread{

            private MyKeyListener[] listeners = new MyKeyListener[0];

            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

            public void addMyKeyListener( MyKeyListener t) {
                MyKeyListener[] tmp = new MyKeyListener[this.listeners.length+1];
                for (int i = 0; i < this.listeners.length; i++)
                tmp[i] = this.listeners[i];
                tmp[this.listeners.length] = t;
                this.listeners = tmp;
            }

            public void run(){
                for(;;){
                   if( CardGame.pressed == true ){
                       fireMyKeyEvent( new MyKeyEvent(this) );
                       System.out.println( "notified" );
                    }
                }
            }

            void fireMyKeyEvent(MyKeyEvent evt) {
                for (int i=0; i<this.listeners.length; i++) {
                    this.listeners[i].keyPressedEvent(evt);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

The player class

```
public class Player implements Runnable
{
    LinkedList<Card> hand;
    String playerName;
    int strategyChosen;
    int playerNumber;

    private boolean running = true;
    private boolean paused = false;

    private Object game;

    public void setPaused( boolean paused ){
        this.paused = paused;
    }

    public synchronized void run(){
       while(running){
         if(!paused){
             if ( playerNumber == 1 ){
                 if( CardGame.playingDeckArray[CardGame.playersNum-1].isEmpty() ){
                 try{
                     System.out.println( "Thread " + playerNumber + " will sleep" );
                     Thread.sleep( 2000 );
                    }catch( InterruptedException e ){
                    }
                }else{
                    System.out.println( "Thread " + playerNumber + " is running" );
                    playGame();
                }
            }else if( CardGame.playingDeckArray[playerNumber-1] == null ){
                 try{
                     System.out.println( "Thread " + playerNumber + " will sleep" );
                     Thread.sleep( 2000 );
                    }catch( InterruptedException e ){
                    }
                }else{
                    System.out.println( "Thread " + playerNumber + " is running" );
                    playGame();
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private void playGame(){
            switch(strategyChosen){
                case 1 : playStratOne();
                break;
                case 2 : playStratTwo();
                break;
            }
    }
```

The key lisntener thread

```
public class MyKeyListenerThread extends Thread implements MyKeyListener{
public void keyPressedEvent( MyKeyEvent evt ){
    Object o = evt.getSource();

    //if( o == "p" ){
        for ( Player player : CardGame.players ){
            player.setPaused( true );
        //}
        //}else if ( o == "r" ){
       // for ( Player player : CardGame.players ){
           // player.setPaused( false );
       // }
    }
}

public void run(){
    for(;;) {
    }
}
}
```

My Key event class

```
public class MyKeyEvent extends EventObject {
public MyKeyEvent(Object source) {
    super(source);
}
}
```

My key listener interface

```
public interface MyKeyListener extends EventListener {
public void keyPressedEvent(MyKeyEvent evt);
}
```

The idea is that when I run the program and the players are playing the game the user should be able to enter p and r whilst the program runs to pause and resume the game, and it should be done using events and listeners, but when I run the program I cant seem to enter input whilst the game runs, or at least the input isn't properly pausing. I am not sure why this is, could someone please help. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than comparing as

```
if(o=="p")
```

in your **MyKeyListenerthread**

compare it with **KeyEvent.VK_P**

Comment: I'm not using the KeyListener which java provides this is a custom event listener so I don't have access to the KeyEvent.VK_P, because from my understanding that class only works with swing GUIs and I need my to work at the command line.